# C++11 equivalent of Windows SRWLock

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm trying to implement my own read/write lock using atomic types. I can easily define exclusive locks, but I fail to create locks for shared reader threads, like SRWLock does (see [SRWLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx)). My question is how to implement locks that can be used in exclusive mode (one reader/writer threads at a time) or in shared mode (multiple reader threads at a time).

I can't use `std::mutex` lock because it doesn't support multiple readers. Also I don't use boost, so no `shared_mutex` either.

Comment: Implement your own that wraps SRWLock and meets the requirements of [BasicLockable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable)?

Comment: [N2406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#shared_mutex_imp) has a reference implementation of `shared_mutex` that can easily be adapted.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27860685/576911 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The shared timed mutex

There is no equivalent for that kind of read-write locking in the C++11 standard library. The good news is that there is one in C++14 and it's called `shared_timed_mutex`.

Take a look here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex

### Compiler support

GCC's recent versions support `shared_timed_mutex` according to [its documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014) if you use the `-std=c++14` compiler flag. The bad news is that Visual C++ doesn't support it yet, or at least I haven't been able to find any concrete info about it, the closest thing I got is [this feature table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) which says that *Shared Locking in C++* is missing.

### Possible alternatives

You can implement this kind of thing using a mutex and a semaphore [as described in this tutorial](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq11-mutex.html) if you use a library that has these primitives.

If you prefer to stay with the standard library, you can implement the stuff with an `std::mutex` and an `std::condition_variable` similarly to [how it's done here](http://austingwalters.com/multithreading-semaphores/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads).

There is also `shared_mutex` in *boost* (as you already noted), or `uv_rwlock_t` in *libuv*, or `pthread_rwlock` in unix-like OSes.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/14, "MSVC STL" added support for shared_timed_mutex in version "19.0 (2015)".